# Horizontal scrollable navigation for carousel

Tags: react-native

I have carousel component and it works fine. Now I'm have to add top navigation (please see example video https://vimeo.com/250800638). I want to create this panel http://joxi.ru/4AkgzvOuM9YYQA

I've failed to find any open source examples and google did not help me. Also I've tryed to create this navigation from scratch, but I don't understand how to move active element to center.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView horizontal overScrollMode="always" contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>Item 1</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>Item 2</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>Item 3</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>Item 4</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>Item 5</Text></View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    marginTop: 50, 
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  item: {
    width: 100,
  }
});
```

I'd like to have a method which allow to set active item (see video above).

Also scrollView does not allow to center last and first items

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Nikita. Please consider including the from-scratch code which you tried to write. Someone may be able to help you fix it to perform the action you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this video a sample of your code? Or something that you would like to achieve? You can animate the position of a list item as you cycle through the carousel. Do you have any code you can provide to see where you are?

Comment: Video shows that I want to achive. Let's forget about carousel, I need only pink top panel. I've updated my question.